# Why do I have to connect ground to earth for my board to work?

Tags: power-supply, ripple, emf

I built a 3d printer myself, Im using an off the shelf controller board with a 24v 400w led power supply that I found for cheap on AliExpress.

The quality of the power supply is far from perfect,It even arrived defective,I found that was due to a bad mov soldering joint.

Anyway, I fixed the PSU, the PSU is on plastic stands, both the PSU and aluminum case are connected to mains earth.

The output of the PSU is connected to a capacitor bank (like a UPS).

At first I noticed some weird behavior with my old LCD display, when I switched to a touch lcd I found that I had to connect the PSU GND to mains earth for it to work, otherwise it wouldn't work at all.

I don't understand why, and the board losses serial connection with my laptop from time to time.

I suspect this has something to do with my crappy PSU, unfortunately I don't have a second 400w psu to test with.

What I don't understand is why do I need to connect GND to earth? The 24v should be insulated from mains right?

I did study electronics at uni but my degree is in computer engineering so we just covered the basic stuff.

Comment: Well, we don't know what power supply it is and how it should be installed and used. You should as you bought it and should have the manuals. PC desktop supplies also connect the output ground return to earth so this power supply does not do that for you.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered this exact problem with touchscreens. If you were to scope that floating gnd with earth ground as your reference, you would almost certainly see 60VPP plus. There's parasitic capacitance (some of it there intentionally for EMI reasons) that causes the supply to not truly float like a battery would.

It's not because your supply is junk. I've encountered this with even expensive supplies. Grounding the supply negative is the best solution I have found. I've tried using tons of filtering but had little success.

As for the serial, the GND line in there is acting as your earth reference, forming a circuit with the parasitic capacitance in the supply. Either current flowing in the ground wire is causing EMI, or the voltage drop across the wire is causing issues with the logic thresholds.

My recommendation is to ground the PSU negative output.

To avoid ground loops, if you're charging your laptop while the printer is connected, use the same outlet as the printer. Alternately you could install a serial isolator.